# How to pass parent/child class as constructor parameter with structuremap?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Interface:

```
public interface IPricingFactorsRepository
{
    IList<LrfInputRates> GetLeaseRateFactorList(
        string programCode, 
        string countryCode, 
        string currencyCode,
        string leaseTerm);
}
```

Got below derived/implemented class:

```
public class PricingFactorsRepository : IPricingFactorsRepository 
{
}

public class OverridePricingFactorsRepository : PricingFactorsRepository
{
}
```

Outside, there is such class that accept the interface as constructor parameter:

```
public class PricingHandler
{
    public PricingHandler(IPricingFactorRepository pricingFactorRepository)
    {
    }
}
```

But with structuremap, it seems I can handle it with only one option:

```
x.For<IPricingFactorsRepository>().Use<PricingFactorsRepository>();
```

In some case, I would like the passed in parameter to be instances of  `PricingFactorsRepository`, some times, it should be `OverridePricingFactorsRepository`.

Comment: How and where do you know what type to use? It sounds like you need a factory approach to create the repository instance if you don't know what type should be used until runtime.

Comment: The type depends on the user selection in GUI. I agree that factory will help. Just wondering if we can configure structuremap to dynamically generate instance of target type.

Comment: With StructureMap you can use named instances to resolve the type based on the name requested, i.e. `.WithName("Override")`, or you could try [Conditional Object Constuction](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/19/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using named instances you can create different objects based on the input:

```
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(conf =>
        {
            conf.For<IPricingFactorsRepository>().Use<PricingFactorsRepository>();
            conf.For<PricingHandler>().Use<PricingHandler>().Named("Default");
            conf.For<PricingHandler>().Add<PricingHandler>().Named("Overriding")
                .Ctor<IPricingFactorsRepository>().Is<OverridePricingFactorsRepository>();
        });
```

Now you can get the different handler configurations by name. The default is the one with the `PricingFactorsRepository`.

```
        var ph = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<PricingHandler>();
        var oph = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<PricingHandler>("Overriding");
```

You'd want to combine this with a factory approach where the object depending on the pricing handler would get the different variants based on the user input.

```
public class PricingHandlerFactory
{
    public PricingHandlerFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public PricingHandler Create(string type)
    {
         var instance = ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<PricingHandler>(type);
         return instance ?? ObjectFactory.GetInstance<PricingHandler>();
    }
}
```

Inject the PricingHandlerFactory where you need it (Structuremap will automatically wire it up, so there should be no need to configure it) and call the `Create` method with the user input to get a `PricingHandler`.

Comment: Thanks. There are some follow up question which i am not able to post here since it is too long. Can you help with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821679/set-constructor-parameter-type-for-structuremap-registry

Comment: Pheiberg, what if PricingFactorsRepository  and OverridePricingFactorsRepository have constructor with one parameter, like x.For<IPricingFactorsRepository>().Use<PricingFactorsRepository>().Ctor<ISession>().Is(a => a.TheInstanceNamed("PSession")); In your codes, how to set the constructor parameter for OverridePricingFactorsRepository?

Comment: @user1637942 - create a named instance for the `OverridePricingFactorsRepository` with the appropriate ctor arguments and add that to the ctor configuration for `PricingHandler`.

Comment: Thanks @PHeiberg, that is exactly what i just did. :). New guy on structuremap. Do you have sometime to help with this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821679/set-constructor-parameter-type-for-structuremap-registry